# How implement codable for Array of dictionary with dynamic keys for using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

API Response is like this

```
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "mobile": "8856969696",
  "demo": [
    {
      "data1": "some"
    },
    {
      "data2": "value"
    }
  ],
  "pay": "12",
}
```

and im trying to parse like this

```
struct demoModel : Codable {
    let status: String?
    let mobile: String?
    let demo : [demoData]?
    let pay: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case status = "status"
        case mobile  = "mobile"
        case demo = "demo"
        case pay = "pay"

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .status)
        mobile  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .mobile )
        demo = try values.decodeIfPresent([demoData].self, forKey: .demo)
        pay = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pay)

    }

}
struct demoData : Codable {
    let data1: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case data1 = "data1"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data1 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .data1)
    }

}
```

Here the response is having an array of dictionary with dynamic keys, Please help me in how to create codable for dynamic keys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic: You don't need CodingKeys if property names are all the same as json names and you don't need to write init(from:) for simple classes, they are synthesized for you by the compiler and lastly do not make a habit of making all properties optional, only use that for json values that can be set to null

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me in how to create codable for dynamic keys .

Well `Codable` protocols are not designed to have dynamic keys, you need to explicitly declare each key, this is not possible for `Codable`.

You would have to use  `[[String: String]]` for those dynamic keys .

Think of it this way, as long as there is no specified  **static** key associated with value, then everything is treated as value of something therefore in your case  `demo` is the key and the dynamic dictionary is it final value you can't decode that as decoding requires a key to decode a value for it, so you can't have dynamic keys .

Comment: @PGDev please help me

Comment: @Raj Added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
class apiResponse{
 var status: String?
 var mobile: String?
 var demo = [[String:Any]]()
 var demoKeys = [String:Any]()

 init(json: [String:Any]){
     self.status = json?["status"] as? String ?? ""
     self.mobile = json?["mobile"] as? String ?? ""
     self.demoKeys = (json?["demo"] as AnyObject) as? [String:Any] ?? [:] 
     for item in demoKeys.keys{
         self.demo.append(json[item] as! [String:Any])
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: You would use the variable demo to fetch the keys.

Comment: please help me with how to access these demo keys, if u provide me exact code it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since `demo` is an `array` of `dictionary` with dynamic keys, you can simply use a `dictionary` of type `[String:String]`, i.e.

```
let demo : [[String:String]]?
```

You simply need to create a single model to parse all that data, i.e.

```
struct DemoModel : Codable {
    let status: String?
    let mobile: String?
    let demo : [[String:String]]?
    let pay: String?
}
```

Points to be noted:

1. There is no need for `demoData`.
2. If the property name of your model exactly match the keys in the JSON, there is no need to explicitly specify `enum CodingKeys`.
3. Since in your `init(from:)` doesn't do anything specific while parsing the JSON, you can avoid that too.

You can parse your data using above model like:

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(DemoModel.self, from: data)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me how to access demo keys